# Is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd, when the amount of operations gets large

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, memory-address

This is my code (sorry, it's long, but there is a lot of repeating code).

{Description}
Sorting algortihm testing program using pseudo randomly
generated number array. User can specify array length,
its min and max elements, the least number of repeating
values. User can also choose how many arrays to be tested.

```
     1  /*=============================================================================
     2   |
     3   |  Assignment:  Program 12
     4   |
     8   |        Class:  Programming Basics
     9   |         Date:  December 13th, 2017
    10   |
    11   |     Language:  GNU C (using gcc on Lenovo Y50-70, OS: Arch Linux x86_64)
    12   |     Version:   0.0
    13   |   To Compile:  gcc -Wall -g -std=c11 pratybos12.c -o pratybos12
    14   |
    15   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    16   |
    17   |  Description:  Sorting algortihm testing program using pseudo randomly 
    18   |                generated number array. User can specify array length, 
    19   |                its min and max elements, the least number of repeating 
    20   |                values. User can also choose how many arrays to be tested.
    21   |
    22   |      Input:    Command line input by user
    23   |
    24   |      Output:   Prompt messages, validation errors and final results
    25   |                are displayed one per line to the standard output.
    26   |                The output is each algorithm's each iteration, with
    27   |                comparison and assignment counts, and also processor
    28   |                clock times and average completion time, in seconds.
    29   |                Finally, the average data of each algorithm is presented.
    30   |                At the end, the algorithms are sorted from best to worst
    31   |                by their average time.
    32   |
    33   | Version
    34   | updates:     Currently this is the intial version
    35   |
    36   +===========================================================================*/
    37  
    38  #include <stdio.h>
    39  #include <stdlib.h>
    40  #include <time.h>
    41  
    42  #include "dbg.h"
    43  
    44  #include "helpers.h"
    45  #include "test_algorithm.h"
    46  
    47  #include "bubble_sort_a.h"
    48  #include "bubble_sort_b.h"
    49  #include "bubble_sort_c.h"
    50  #include "bubble_sort_d.h"
    51  #include "bubble_sort_e.h"
    52  #include "bubble_sort_e_and_f.h"
    53  #include "bubble_sort_f.h"
    54  #include "bubble_sort_b_and_c.h"
    55  #include "bubble_sort_b_and_e.h"
    56  #include "bubble_sort_b_and_f.h"
    57  #include "bubble_sort_c_and_e.h"
    58  #include "bubble_sort_c_and_f.h"
    59  #include "bubble_sort_b_and_e_and_f.h"
    60  #include "bubble_sort_b_and_c_and_e_and_f.h"
    61  #include "insertion_sort.h"
    62  #include "quicksort_pivot_first.h"
    63  #include "selection_sort.h"
    64  #include "top_down_merge_sort.h"
    65  
    66  #define MAX_ITER 100
    67  #define MAX_ALGO 100
    68  
    69  
    70  typedef struct {
    71      char* pointerName;
    72      int pointerMemory;
    73  } PointerStats;
    74  
    75  typedef struct {
    76      PointerStats* memJournal;
    77      int JournalPointerCount;
    78      int memUsed;
    79      int memUsedByJournal;
    80  } MemoryStats;
    81  
    82  
    83  typedef struct {
    84      int no;
    85      int is_sorted;
    86      int comp_count;
    87      int assign_count;
    88      double clocks_total;
    89      double time_spent;
    90  } Iteration;
    91  
    92  typedef struct {
    93      char* type;
    94      char* complexity;
    95      int iter_count;
    96      int rank;
    97      int avg_comp;
    98      int avg_assign;
    99      double avg_clocks;
   100      double avg_time;
   101      Iteration* iterations[MAX_ITER];
   102  } Algorithm;
   103  
   104  typedef struct {
   105      char* date;
   106      char* arch;
   107      char* compiler;
   108      Algorithm* algorithms[MAX_ALGO];
   109  } Results;
   110  
   111  // a typedef creates a fake type, in this
   112  // case for a sort function pointer
   113  typedef int* (*sort_pointer)(int* target, int size);
   114  
   115  // function pointer to a quicksort function
   116  typedef int* (*quicksort_pointer)(int* target, int first, int last);
   117  
   118  // function pointer to a mergesort function
   119  typedef void (*mergesort_pointer)(int* target, int* working_array, int size);
   120  
   121  
   122  void filldata(int* data, int size, int min, int max, int repeat);
   123  void test_sort( int* data, int size, sort_pointer func, Algorithm* Algo, int no);
   124  void test_quicksort( int* data, int size, quicksort_pointer func, Algorithm* Algo, int no);
   125  void test_mergesort( int* data, int size, mergesort_pointer func, Algorithm* Algo, int no);
   126  void print_algo(Algorithm* Algo);
   127  void calculate_average(Algorithm* Algo);
   128  Algorithm** rank_algorithms(Algorithm** target, int first, int last);
   129  
   130  MemoryStats memoryStats;
   131  
   132  int array_count;
   133  
   134  int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   135  {
   136      srand(time(NULL));
   137  
   138      Results* Res = malloc(sizeof(Results));
   139  
   140      Res->date = "2017-12-16";
   141      Res->arch = "Arch Linux x86_64";
   142      Res->compiler = "gcc";
   143  
   144      // creating algorithm structures
   145      Algorithm* Algo1 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   146      Algo1->type = "bubble_sort_a";
   147      Algo1->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   148  
   149      Algorithm* Algo2 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   150      Algo2->type = "bubble_sort_b";
   151      Algo2->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   152  
   153      Algorithm* Algo3 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   154      Algo3->type = "bubble_sort_c";
   155      Algo3->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   156  
   157      Algorithm* Algo4 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   158      Algo4->type = "bubble_sort_d";
   159      Algo4->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   160  
   161      Algorithm* Algo5 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   162      Algo5->type = "bubble_sort_e";
   163      Algo5->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   164  
   165      Algorithm* Algo6 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   166      Algo6->type = "bubble_sort_f";
   167      Algo6->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   168  
   169      Algorithm* Algo7 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   170      Algo7->type = "bubble_sort_b_and_c";
   171      Algo7->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   172  
   173      Algorithm* Algo8 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   174      Algo8->type = "bubble_sort_b_and_e";
   175      Algo8->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   176  
   177      Algorithm* Algo9 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   178      Algo9->type = "bubble_sort_b_and_f";
   179      Algo9->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   180  
   181      Algorithm* Algo10 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   182      Algo10->type = "bubble_sort_c_and_e";
   183      Algo10->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   184  
   185      Algorithm* Algo11 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   186      Algo11->type = "bubble_sort_c_and_f";
   187      Algo11->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   188  
   189      Algorithm* Algo12 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   190      Algo12->type = "bubble_sort_e_and_f";
   191      Algo12->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   192  
   193      Algorithm* Algo13 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   194      Algo13->type = "bubble_sort_b_and_e_and_f";
   195      Algo13->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   196  
   197      Algorithm* Algo14 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   198      Algo14->type = "bubble_sort_b_and_c_and_e_and_f";
   199      Algo14->complexity = "O (n^2)";
   200  
   201      Algorithm* Algo15 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   202      Algo15->type = "quicksort";
   203      Algo15->complexity = "O (n logn n)";
   204  
   205      Algorithm* Algo16 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   206      Algo16->type = "insertion_sort";
   207      Algo16->complexity = "O (2n)";
   208  
   209      Algorithm* Algo17 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   210      Algo17->type = "selection_sort";
   211      Algo17->complexity = "O (2n)";
   212  
   213      Algorithm* Algo18 = malloc(sizeof(Algorithm));
   214      Algo18->type = "top down merge sort";
   215      Algo18->complexity = "O (n log n)";
   216  
   217      Res->algorithms[0] = Algo1;
   218      Res->algorithms[1] = Algo2;
   219      Res->algorithms[2] = Algo3;
   220      Res->algorithms[3] = Algo4;
   221      Res->algorithms[4] = Algo5;
   222      Res->algorithms[5] = Algo6;
   223      Res->algorithms[6] = Algo7;
   224      Res->algorithms[7] = Algo8;
   225      Res->algorithms[8] = Algo9;
   226      Res->algorithms[9] = Algo10;
   227      Res->algorithms[10] = Algo11;
   228      Res->algorithms[11] = Algo12;
   229      Res->algorithms[12] = Algo13;
   230      Res->algorithms[13] = Algo14;
   231      Res->algorithms[14] = Algo15;
   232      Res->algorithms[15] = Algo16;
   233      Res->algorithms[16] = Algo17;
   234      Res->algorithms[17] = Algo18;
   235  
   236      memoryStats.memJournal = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
   237  
   238      memoryStats.memUsedByJournal = 10;
   239  
   240      memoryStats.JournalPointerCount = 0;
   241  
   242      printf("Mem used total: %d\n", memoryStats.memUsed);
   243  
   244      int size;
   245      int min;
   246      int max;
   247      int repeat;
   248  
   249      array_count = get_pos_num("How many arrays would you like to test? > ", 0);
   250      size = get_pos_num("What is the size of each array? > ", 0);
   251      min = get_pos_num("What is the minimum number in each array? > ", 0);
   252      max = get_pos_num("What is the maximum number in each array? > ", 0);
   253  
   254      while (1) {
   255          printf("How many repeating values there will be AT LEAST? > ");
   256          if (scanf("%d", &repeat) == 1 && repeat >= 0
   257              && repeat <= (max - min + 1) && getchar() == '\n') {
   258              break;
   259          } else {
   260              while (getchar() != '\n')
   261                  ;
   262              printf("Please enter a positive integer or zero, which is not "
   263                     "greater than the "
   264                     "size of the array\n");
   265          }
   266      }
   267  
   268      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   269          int* data = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
   270  
   271          filldata(data, size, min, max, repeat);
   272          if (data == NULL)
   273              die("Atminties problema");
   274  
   275          printf("i: %d", i);
   276          print_array(data, size, "Your generated numbers:");
   277          //---------------------------USING FUNCTION POINTERS-----------------//
   278  
   279          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_a, Algo1, i + 1);
   280          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b, Algo2, i + 1);
   281          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_c, Algo3, i + 1);
   282          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_d, Algo4, i + 1);
   283          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_e, Algo5, i + 1);
   284          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_f, Algo6, i + 1);
   285          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b_and_c, Algo7, i + 1);
   286          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b_and_e, Algo8, i + 1);
   287          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b_and_f, Algo9, i + 1);
   288          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_c_and_e, Algo10, i + 1);
   289          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_c_and_f, Algo11, i + 1);
   290          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_e_and_f, Algo12, i + 1);
   291          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b_and_e_and_f, Algo13, i + 1);
   292          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b_and_c_and_e_and_f, Algo14, i + 1);
   293  
   294          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_c_and_f, Algo15, i + 1);
   295          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_e_and_f, Algo16, i + 1);
   296          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b_and_e_and_f, Algo17, i + 1);
   297          test_sort(data, size, &bubble_sort_b_and_c_and_e_and_f, Algo18, i + 1);
   298  
   299  
   300          free(data);
   301      }
   302  
   303      calculate_average(Algo1);
   304      calculate_average(Algo2);
   305      calculate_average(Algo3);
   306      calculate_average(Algo4);
   307      calculate_average(Algo5);
   308      calculate_average(Algo6);
   309      calculate_average(Algo7);
   310      calculate_average(Algo8);
   311      calculate_average(Algo9);
   312      calculate_average(Algo10);
   313      calculate_average(Algo11);
   314      calculate_average(Algo12);
   315      calculate_average(Algo13);
   316      calculate_average(Algo14);
   317      calculate_average(Algo15);
   318      calculate_average(Algo16);
   319      calculate_average(Algo17);
   320      calculate_average(Algo18);
   321  
   322  
   323      for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
   324          print_algo(Res->algorithms[i]);
   325      }
   326  
   327  
   328      Algorithm** target = malloc(18 * sizeof(Algorithm));
   329  
   330      target[0] = Algo1;
   331      target[1] = Algo2;
   332      target[2] = Algo3;
   333      target[3] = Algo4;
   334      target[4] = Algo5;
   335      target[5] = Algo6;
   336      target[6] = Algo7;
   337      target[7] = Algo8;
   338      target[8] = Algo9;
   339      target[9] = Algo10;
   340      target[10] = Algo11;
   341      target[11] = Algo12;
   342      target[12] = Algo13;
   343      target[13] = Algo14;
   344      target[14] = Algo15;
   345      target[15] = Algo16;
   346      target[16] = Algo17;
   347      target[17] = Algo18;
   348  
   349      target = rank_algorithms(target, 0, 17);
   350  
   351      printf("Fastest algorithms (ranking):\n");
   352      printf("=============================\n");
   353  
   354      for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
   355          printf("%d. ", i + 1);
   356          printf("%s\n", target[i]->type);
   357          printf("Average time: %f\n", target[i]->avg_time);
   358          printf("---------------------------------\n");
   359      }
   360  
   361      printf("================================\n");
   362      printf("Date: %s\n", Res->date);
   363      printf("Architecture: %s\n", Res->arch);
   364      printf("Compiler: %s\n", Res->compiler);
   365      printf("================================\n");
   366  
   367      printf("Mem used total: %d\n", memoryStats.memUsed);
   368  
   369  
   370      free(Res);
   371  
   372  
   373      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   374          free(Algo1->iterations[i]);
   375      }
   376      free(Algo1);
   377  
   378      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   379          free(Algo2->iterations[i]);
   380      }
   381      free(Algo2);
   382  
   383      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   384          free(Algo3->iterations[i]);
   385      }
   386      free(Algo3);
   387  
   388      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   389          free(Algo4->iterations[i]);
   390      }
   391      free(Algo4);
   392  
   393      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   394          free(Algo5->iterations[i]);
   395      }
   396      free(Algo5);
   397  
   398      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   399          free(Algo6->iterations[i]);
   400      }
   401      free(Algo6);
   402  
   403      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   404          free(Algo7->iterations[i]);
   405      }
   406      free(Algo7);
   407  
   408      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   409          free(Algo8->iterations[i]);
   410      }
   411      free(Algo8);
   412  
   413      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   414          free(Algo9->iterations[i]);
   415      }
   416      free(Algo9);
   417  
   418      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   419          free(Algo10->iterations[i]);
   420      }
   421      free(Algo10);
   422  
   423      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   424          free(Algo11->iterations[i]);
   425      }
   426      free(Algo11);
   427      
   428      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   429          free(Algo12->iterations[i]);
   430      }
   431      free(Algo12);
   432  
   433      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   434          free(Algo13->iterations[i]);
   435      }
   436      free(Algo13);
   437      
   438      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   439          free(Algo14->iterations[i]);
   440      }
   441      free(Algo14);
   442  
   443      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   444          free(Algo15->iterations[i]);
   445      }
   446      free(Algo15);
   447      
   448      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   449          free(Algo16->iterations[i]);
   450      }
   451      free(Algo16);
   452  
   453      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   454          free(Algo17->iterations[i]);
   455      }
   456      free(Algo17);
   457  
   458      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   459          free(Algo18->iterations[i]);
   460      }
   461      free(Algo18);
   462  
   463      free(target);
   464      free(memoryStats.memJournal);
   465  }
   466  
   467  
   468  void filldata(int* data, int size, int min, int max, int repeat)
   469  {
   470      int i;
   471  
   472      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
   473          data[i] = min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
   474      }
   475  
   476      if (repeat > 1) {
   477          int repeat_value = min + rand() % (max - min + 1);
   478  
   479          int indexes[repeat];
   480  
   481          int x;
   482  
   483          // Non-duplicate number generation
   484  
   485          i = 0;
   486          while (i < repeat) {
   487              int index = rand() % size;
   488  
   489              for (x = 0; x < i; x++) {
   490                  if (indexes[x] == index) {
   491                      break;
   492                  }
   493              }
   494              if (x == i) {
   495                  indexes[i++] = index;
   496              }
   497          }
   498  
   499          for (i = 0; i < repeat; i++) {
   500              data[indexes[i]] = repeat_value;
   501          }
   502      }
   503  }
   504  
   505  
   506  void test_sort(int* data, int size, sort_pointer func, Algorithm* Algo, int no)
   507  {
   508  
   509      count_ncomp = 0;
   510      count_assign = 0;
   511  
   512      begin = clock();
   513  
   514      int* target = NULL;
   515      target = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
   516      if (!target)
   517          die("Memory error.");
   518  
   519      memcpy(target, data, size * sizeof(int));
   520  
   521      Iteration* Iter = malloc(sizeof(Iteration));
   522      if (Iter == NULL) {
   523          exit(1);
   524      }
   525      Iter->no = no;
   526  
   527      if (is_sorted(func(target, size), size)) {
   528          end = clock();
   529          clocks = (double)(end - begin);
   530          time_spent = clocks / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
   531  
   532          Iter->is_sorted = 1;
   533          Iter->comp_count = count_ncomp;
   534          Iter->assign_count = count_assign;
   535          Iter->clocks_total = clocks;
   536          Iter->time_spent = time_spent;
   537      } else {
   538          Iter->is_sorted = 0;
   539          
   540      };
   541  
   542      Algo->iterations[no - 1] = Iter;
   543  
   544      if (target == NULL) {
   545          debug("Target is NULL");
   546      }
   547  
   548      free(target);
   549  }
   550  
   551  
   552  void print_algo(Algorithm* Algo)
   553  {
   554  
   555      printf("Algorithm type: %s\n", Algo->type);
   556      printf("Time complexity: %s\n", Algo->complexity);
   557      printf("----------------------------------\n");
   558      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   559          if (!Algo->iterations[i]->is_sorted) {
   560              printf("Not sorted");
   561          } else {
   562              printf("no: %d\n", Algo->iterations[i]->no);
   563              printf("is_sorted: True\n");
   564              printf("comp_count: %d\n", Algo->iterations[i]->comp_count);
   565              printf("assign count: %d\n", Algo->iterations[i]->assign_count);
   566              printf("clocks total: %f\n", Algo->iterations[i]->clocks_total);
   567              printf("time spent: %f\n", Algo->iterations[i]->time_spent);
   568          }
   569          printf("----------------------------------\n");
   570      }
   571      printf("Iteration count: %d\n", Algo->iter_count);
   572      printf("Average compare count: %d\n", Algo->avg_comp);
   573      printf("Average assign count: %d\n", Algo->avg_assign);
   574      printf("Average clocks: %f\n", Algo->avg_clocks);
   575      printf("Average time spent: %f\n", Algo->avg_time);
   576  
   577      printf("===================================\n");
   578  }
   579  
   580  void calculate_average(Algorithm* Algo)
   581  {
   582      int sum_comp = 0;
   583      int sum_assign = 0;
   584      double sum_clocks = 0;
   585      double sum_time = 0;
   586      int sorted_count = array_count;
   587  
   588      for (int i = 0; i < array_count; i++) {
   589  
   590          debug("is sorted %d", Algo->iterations[i]->is_sorted);
   591          debug("Array count: %d", i);
   592  
   593          if (!Algo->iterations[i]->is_sorted) {
   594              sorted_count--;
   595          } else {
   596              sum_comp += Algo->iterations[i]->comp_count;
   597              sum_assign += Algo->iterations[i]->assign_count;
   598              sum_clocks += Algo->iterations[i]->clocks_total;
   599              sum_time += Algo->iterations[i]->time_spent;
   600          }
   601      }
   602      if (sorted_count > 0) {
   603          Algo->avg_comp = sum_comp / sorted_count;
   604          Algo->avg_assign = sum_assign / sorted_count;
   605          Algo->avg_clocks = (double)(sum_clocks / sorted_count);
   606          Algo->avg_time = (double)(sum_time / sorted_count);
   607          Algo->iter_count = sorted_count;
   608      }
   609  }
   610  
   611  Algorithm** rank_algorithms(Algorithm** target, int first, int last)
   612  {
   613  
   614      Algorithm* temp;
   615      int pivot, j, i;
   616  
   617      if (first < last) {
   618          pivot = first;
   619          i = first;
   620          j = last;
   621  
   622          while (i < j) {
   623              while (
   624                  target[i]->avg_time <= target[pivot]->avg_time && i < last) {
   625                  i++;
   626              }
   627              while (target[j]->avg_time > target[pivot]->avg_time) {
   628                  j--;
   629              }
   630              if (i < j) {
   631                  temp = target[i];
   632                  target[i] = target[j];
   633                  target[j] = temp;
   634              }
   635          }
   636  
   637          temp = target[pivot];
   638          target[pivot] = target[j];
   639          target[j] = temp;
   640  
   641          rank_algorithms(target, first, j - 1);
   642          rank_algorithms(target, j + 1, last);
   643      }
   644      return target;
   645  }
   646
```

What I can successfully do (running a program):

```
How many arrays would you like to test? > 100
What is the size of each array? > 10
What is the minimum number in each array? > 1
What is the maximum number in each array? > 10
How many repeating values there will be AT LEAST? > 0
```

What I can't do:

```
How many arrays would you like to test? > 1000
What is the size of each array? > 10
What is the minimum number in each array? > 1
What is the maximum number in each array? > 10
How many repeating values there will be AT LEAST? > 0
```

The problem is when there are 1000 arrays to be tested (instead of 100).
This is the same error I get:

```
DEBUG pratybos12.c:590: is sorted 1
DEBUG pratybos12.c:591: Array count: 919
==5798== Invalid read of size 4
==5798==    at 0x10A646: calculate_average (pratybos12.c:590)
==5798==    by 0x1096F5: main (pratybos12.c:313)
==5798==  Address 0x2d2d2d2d2d2d2d31 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==5798==
==5798==
==5798== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==5798==  General Protection Fault
==5798==    at 0x10A646: calculate_average (pratybos12.c:590)
==5798==    by 0x1096F5: main (pratybos12.c:313)
```

The question is, how to even start debugging it, ie where the problem might be.

A few notes:
(1) When I run it with 100 arrays (first case), Valgrind reports that all memory is successfully freed, no leaks occur.

(2) I had a "double free or corruption error" in line 300:

```
  300          free(data);
```

but I turned it off by setting MALLOC_CHECK_ to 0.

Comment: That's not a [***Minimal***, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Therefore http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/

Comment: Too much code, please post a [mcve], chances are that you can't write one because your code suffers a lot from repetition which is perhaps the real cause of the problem.

Comment: Besides that, have you tried looking at line 590 of your code? What happens *around* there? And if you don't know where to start debugging, then just start at the beginning. It might be tedious but it's a part of working as a programmer.

Comment: Thanks, duly noted. I will try to reframe (MCVE) my question next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The size of `Algorithm.iterations` is `MAX_ITER` which is 100. And then you access `Algorithm.iterations` elements up to 1000th. This is undefined behavior.
2. `Algorithm** target = malloc(18 * sizeof(Algorithm));` is wrong for sure. The type of `target` should be `Algorithm *`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look through the code and answer. Those mistakes (kinda silly, actually) were exactly the reason! Dėkui! :)